# Streaming video resets my internet connection through LAN adapter on Windows 11

Tags: windows, networking, drivers, webcam

As soon as I got my new Dell XPS 15 9510, I started noticing some odd behavior. If I simultaneously use the webcam with any program (Microsoft Teams, Google Meet, Stream Yard), my internet connection will be reset, just like if I don't have a network card.
The PC already had Windows 10 on it when I got it, and I use a LAN adapter to connect to the internet.

These are the steps I took in an effort to solve:

- Updated to Windows 11
- Updated all NVIDIA and DELL drivers
- Set the camera to use local drivers instead NVIDIA ones
- Installed an external camera
- Disabled the internal camera
- Tried to use meet with another browser like Edge or Firefox
- Changed the LAN adapter

In any case I noticed some improvements. It's frustating! Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps file an issue with Dell Support

Comment: Open up Device Manager, expand Network adapters, and test your webcam again. Does the list change or refresh at all? What are you using as a LAN adapter?

Comment: @John Maybe I can try to contact them

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Yes, the list doesn't change but sometimes it refreshes. I'm using a VAVA 9 to 1 with LAN, USB-c, etc, but I tried other adapters and the result was the same.

Comment: Try the webcam again, then check the windows Event Log>Security>filter for ID:6416. If you see one of these for your LAN adapter, then the webcam is causing some power issues. Dell may blame the adapters though.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I checked the log but I didn't find that entry, but you helped me to identify the issue. I bought an adapter that has only the LAN port and until now I'm able to do call without problems. So, I think was a power issue problem generated by the adapter.

Comment: And as I said I resolved, it started again...It went better without an all-in-one adapter, but the issue is still here! And I don't think Dell will help more.